# ROWID Error on oracle view with left join

Tags: oracle, join, left-join, oracle12c

So, i obtained this select from a view which has been causing errors when used, and i got this select.

This was the original query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESUMEN_VENTA_PRODUCTOS
(
  PRODUCTO,
  M_PRODUCT_ID,
  C_INVOICE_ID,
  C_PROJECTOFB_ID,
  C_DOCTYPE_ID,
  TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
  NETO,
  C_CURRENCY_ID,
  MONEDA,
  FECHA_DOC,
  NUMERO_DOC,
  FECHA_CREACION_PRO,
  RUT_NUMERO,
  RUT_DV,
  EJECUTIVO,
  EVALUACION_PRE,
  FALLA_TIPO,
  FALLA_CAT,
  CATEGORIA,
  INGENIERO,
  ORIGEN,
  PRECIO_MINIMO
)
AS 
select 
  p.name as producto, il.m_product_id, i.c_invoice_id, i.c_projectofb_id, i.c_doctype_id, dt.name as tipo_documento, 
CASE WHEN charat (dt.docbasetype, 3) = 'C' AND dt.docbasetype <> 'CDC' then
il.linenetamt *-1
else
il.linenetamt
end as neto
, curr.c_currency_id,
curr.iso_code as moneda, i.dateinvoiced as fecha_doc, i.documentno as numero_doc,
pro.created as fecha_creacion_pro,
bp.value as rut_numero, bp.digito as rut_dv,
u.name as ejecutivo,
rltspe.name as evaluacion_pre,
rltftspr.name as falla_tipo,
rltfcspr.name as falla_cat,
pc.name as categoria,
ing.name as ingeniero
, rlt_o.name as ORIGEN
, pro.precio_minimo
from c_invoiceline il
left join c_invoice i
on (il.c_invoice_id = i.c_invoice_id)
left join m_product p
on (il.m_product_id = p.m_product_id)

left join m_product_category pc
on (p.m_product_category_id = pc.m_product_category_id)

left join c_projectofb pro
on (i.c_projectofb_id = pro.c_projectofb_id)
left join ad_user ing
on (pro.salesrep_id = ing.ad_user_id)
left join c_doctype dt
on (i.c_doctypetarget_id = dt.c_doctype_id)
left join c_currency curr
on (i.c_currency_id = curr.c_currency_id)
left join c_bpartner bp
on (i.c_bpartner_id = bp.c_bpartner_id)
left join ad_user u
on (i.salesrep_id = u.ad_user_id)
left join c_subprojectofb spe
on (pro.c_projectofb_id = spe.c_projectofb_id and spe.typeprojectkepler = '00')
left join c_subprojectofb spr
on (pro.c_projectofb_id = spr.c_projectofb_id and spr.typeprojectkepler = '01')
left join ad_ref_list rlspe
on (spe.evaluationpre_kp = rlspe.value and rlspe.ad_reference_id = 1000021)
left join AD_Ref_List_Trl rltspe
on (rlspe.ad_ref_list_id = rltspe.ad_ref_list_id)

left join ad_ref_list rlftspr
on (spr.falla_tipo = rlftspr.value and rlftspr.ad_reference_id = 1000053)
left join AD_Ref_List_Trl rltftspr
on (rlftspr.ad_ref_list_id = rltftspr.ad_ref_list_id)

left join ad_ref_list rlfcspr
on (spr.falla_cat = rlfcspr.value and rlfcspr.ad_reference_id = 1000052)
left join AD_Ref_List_Trl rltfcspr
on (rlfcspr.ad_ref_list_id = rltfcspr.ad_ref_list_id)

left join c_preproyecto pp
on (i.c_projectofb_id = pp.c_projectofb_id)
left join ad_ref_list rl_o
on (pp.origen = rl_o.value and rl_o.ad_reference_id = 1000059)
left join AD_Ref_List_Trl rlt_o
on (rl_o.ad_ref_list_id = rlt_o.ad_ref_list_id)
/*
left join ad_ref_list rl_est
on (pro.estado = rl_est.value and rl_est.ad_reference_id = 1000017)
left join AD_Ref_List_Trl rlt_est
on (rl_est.ad_ref_list_id = rlt_est.ad_ref_list_id)
*/
where i.docstatus = 'CO' and i.issotrx = 'Y'
and pro.typeprojectkepler = '01'
order by i.dateinvoiced desc;



GRANT SELECT ON RESUMEN_VENTA_PRODUCTOS TO KEPLER;
```

so i modified it to:

```
select p.name as producto, 
il.m_product_id, 
i.c_invoice_id, 
i.c_projectofb_id, 
i.c_doctype_id, 
dt.name as tipo_documento, 
CASE WHEN DT.C_DOCTYPE_ID IN (1000004,1000006,1000069,1000071,50013,1000120,1000121,1000135,1000144,1000086,1000099,1000105,1000107,1000113,1000021,1000048,1000049,141,124,118,1000037,1000039) 
AND dt.docbasetype <> 'CDC' 
then il.linenetamt *-1
else il.linenetamt
end as neto, 
curr.c_currency_id,
curr.iso_code as moneda, 
i.dateinvoiced as fecha_doc, 
i.documentno as numero_doc,
pro.created as fecha_creacion_pro,
bp.value as rut_numero, 
bp.digito as rut_dv,
u.name as ejecutivo,
rltspe.name as evaluacion_pre,
rltftspr.name as falla_tipo,
rltfcspr.name as falla_cat,
pc.name as categoria,
ing.name as ingeniero
,rlt_o.name as ORIGEN
,pro.precio_minimo
from c_invoiceline il
left join c_invoice i
on (il.c_invoice_id = i.c_invoice_id)
left join m_product p
on (il.m_product_id = p.m_product_id)
left join m_product_category pc
on (p.m_product_category_id = pc.m_product_category_id)
left join c_projectofb pro
on (i.c_projectofb_id = pro.c_projectofb_id)
left join ad_user ing
on (pro.salesrep_id = ing.ad_user_id)
left join c_doctype dt
on (i.c_doctypetarget_id = dt.c_doctype_id)
left join c_currency curr
on (i.c_currency_id = curr.c_currency_id)
left join c_bpartner bp
on (i.c_bpartner_id = bp.c_bpartner_id)
left join ad_user u
on (i.salesrep_id = u.ad_user_id)
left join c_subprojectofb spe
on (pro.c_projectofb_id = spe.c_projectofb_id and spe.typeprojectkepler = '00')
left join c_subprojectofb spr
on (pro.c_projectofb_id = spr.c_projectofb_id and spr.typeprojectkepler = '01')
left join ad_ref_list rlspe
on (spe.evaluationpre_kp = rlspe.value and rlspe.ad_reference_id = 1000021)
left join ad_ref_list rlftspr
on (spr.falla_tipo = rlftspr.value and rlftspr.ad_reference_id = 1000053)
full join AD_Ref_List_Trl rltspe
on (rlspe.ad_ref_list_id = rltspe.ad_ref_list_id)
left join AD_Ref_List_Trl rltftspr
on (rlftspr.ad_ref_list_id = rltftspr.ad_ref_list_id)
left join ad_ref_list rlfcspr
on (spr.falla_cat = rlfcspr.value and rlfcspr.ad_reference_id = 1000052)
left join AD_Ref_List_Trl rltfcspr
on (rlfcspr.ad_ref_list_id = rltfcspr.ad_ref_list_id)
left join c_preproyecto pp
on (i.c_projectofb_id = pp.c_projectofb_id)
left join ad_ref_list rl_o
on (pp.origen = rl_o.value and rl_o.ad_reference_id = 1000059)
left join AD_Ref_List_Trl rlt_o
on (rl_o.ad_ref_list_id = rlt_o.ad_ref_list_id)
where i.docstatus = 'CO' and i.issotrx = 'Y'
and pro.typeprojectkepler = '01';
order by i.dateinvoiced desc;
```

because the first CASE WHEN gave me an ORA-01455 error.

After modifying it, and when i ran the second select i obtained this message

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select p.name as producto, 
il.m_product_id, 
i.c_invoice_id, 
i.c_projectofb_id, 
i.c_doctype_id, 
dt.name as tipo_documento, 
CASE WHEN DT.C_DOCTYPE...

Error at line 54:
ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table
full join AD_Ref_List_Trl rltspe
          ^

Execution time: 1.3s
Statement 1 of 2 finished


Script execution finished
Total script execution time: 1.3s
```

i have tried using full join, right join, inner join, outer join, and nothing seems to work, more than removin the said section of the query, i'm getting out of ideas here, so i decided to ask here for any help on the case.

Everything will be really appreciated

Comment: Don't spam tags. If your question is about Oracle, don't use the `mysql` tag.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. The emphasis is on **minimal** in your case. Minimize it so it shows the problem but nothing more.

Comment: There's no rowid in the provided queries. Also the joins do not matter, because the error text is clearly says that you may select rowid only from key-preserved table of the view. Check the error explanation and possible actions [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903)

Comment: If `AD_Ref_List_Trl` is the line that is throwing the error, is that object a table?  Or a view?

Comment: @JustinCave it's a table

Comment: @astentx thx, been checking that, weird thing is, whis view worked for years and just now it's failing, so i'm suspecting a bug. I will check on recently added data tho.